# Is it a good practice to use multiple components to make up a view?

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS, I want to know if my view is very complex, for example, there's toolbar, navigation bar, and several other parts. If I assign one controller to the entire view, the controller will be very big. So, I want each of the parts has their own controller, after researching, I found angular component could help me achieve the goal. But I'm not sure whether it is a good practice to use multiple components to make up a view, if not, what's the common way to implement it?

Comment: Your question is too broad, and opinion-based. You should ask a question on a more precise example and insert a corresponding code snippet

Comment: That is true that your question is too broad and opinion-based - but the answer is yes - components, directives and even includes are meant to be used when creating a composite ui.

Comment: your toolbar, navigation bar should be directives. they have their own controllers. you then can combine all these directives in one view. the view has his own controller too.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **YES**. It is a very good practice in programming to divide code into components rather than writing all in one huge file. Not matter whether it's Angular or not.